# Distinct Balls and distict Urns with constraint maximum

Tags: combinatorics

I'm looking for a some help with a general expression.  I'm trying to put $k$ distinct balls into $n$ distinct urns, but each urn can only hold up to $c$ balls, with $cn \geq k$.

I know there are $n^k$ permutations, but how do I enforce the constraint?

Answer (score 3):

The number of ways to put $k$ balls in $n$ bins where each bin can only hold up to $c$ balls is the coefficient of $z^k$ in the $n^{\text{th}}$ power of the ordinary generating function $1+x+\dots+x^c$, i.e., $$[z^k]\left(\sum_{i=0}^c z^i\right)^n.$$
The finite geometric series is equivalent to $\frac{1-z^{c+1}}{1-z}$. Expanding the numerator with the binomial theorem, this is equivalent to $$[z^k]\frac{\sum_{i=0}^n\binom ni(-1)^i z^{i(c+1)}}{(1-z)^n}.$$
The generating function for the denominator is $\sum_{i\ge0}\binom{n-1+i}{n-1}z^i$. Multiplying these together gives an explicit formula for the desired count, namely $$\sum_{i=0}^n \binom ni(-1)^i\binom{n-1+k-i(c+1)}{n-1}.$$

Answer (score 1):

I assume by "*distinct*" you mean *distinguishable*.

In that case, the desired result if empty bins are allowed is

$\text{balls}! \left[z^{\text{balls}}\right] \left(\sum _{k=0}^{\text{capacity}} \frac{z^k}{k!}\right){}^{\text{bins}}$

and if no empty bins are allowed

$\text{balls}! \left[z^{\text{balls}}\right] \left(\sum _{k=1}^{\text{capacity}} \frac{z^k}{k!}\right){}^{\text{bins}}$

In both, $\left[z^{\text{balls}}\right]$ is the *coefficient extraction*, e.g. the coefficient of $z$ for exponent $balls$ in the subsequent factors.

Comment: The generating functions shouldn't have the factorials in the denominators; they're just geometric series. In this case, they're summable, and using the binomial theorem you can get an explicit formula for the coefficients.

Comment: @RusMay: Rus, thanks for comment - might you clarify? I grabbed those from a list I've built over the years (I think those came from the "Urn models" book IIRC). Are you saying the result is incorrect, or that it can be simplified (I seem to recall searching for a simpler expression/pattern and not finding one).

Comment: Right, this is a case for an ordinary generating function, not an exponential. The clarification uses some formulas (which are a lot easier to read in an answer as opposed to a comment), so I put them there.

Comment: The balls are distinct so I think this is the correct answer... @RusMay solution is if the balls are not distinguishable (I think).

Comment: @HammyTheGreek Suppose capacity is 1, namely no repetitions, we have $n$ balls and $g$ bins. Then your formula gives $[z^n](1+z)^g=\binom{g}{n}$ by Newton's theorem, but this is wrong because $n$-permutations of $g$ elements are $g!/(g-n)!$. Could you please check your result?

Comment: I guess the result is essentially right, but you have to extract the coefficient of $z^n$ *and* multiply by $n!$ to get the right answer (see my answer for more details).

Answer (score 0):

Let me derive @Rus May's formula, using the method proposed in [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1248392/combinations-with-maximum-allowed-repetition).

We want to know in how many ways $C^{(s)}_{n,g}$ we can put $n\ge0$ *undistinguishable* spheres into $g\ge0$ urns, with at most $s\ge1$ spheres in a given urn. We proceed by induction; consider the first urn: we can put into it a number $i$ of balls from zero (no spheres) to either $s$ or, if we have fewer than $s$ spheres in total, $n$. Once we have done this, we are back to the starting problem, but with $n-i$ spheres and $g-1$ boxes. 
As a consequence we get the following recurrence relation:
$$
C^{(s)}_{n,g}=\sum_{i=0}^{\mathrm{min}(n,s)}C^{(s)}_{n-i,g-1}\,.
$$
The boundary terms are $C^{(s)}_{0,g}=1$ for all $g\ge0$ and $C^{(s)}_{n,0}=0$ if $n\ge1$. We define the generating functions
$$
f_g^{(s)}(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty C^{(s)}_{n,g} x^n\,,
$$
namely,
$$
C^{(s)}_{n,g} = [z^n]f_g^{(s)}(x)\,.
$$
By the above boundary relations, the $g=0$ function also satifies $f_0^{(s)}(x)=1$. Next we multiply the recurrence relaition for $C^{(s)}_{n,g}$ by $x^n$ and sum over $n$ from 0 to infinity: we adopt the conventions that whenever a $C^{(s)}_{n,g}$ is evaluated outside its range of validity (its ''support'') it gives zero, thus
$$
\begin{aligned}
\sum_{n=0}^\infty C^{(s)}_{n,g} x^{n} &= \sum_{n=0}^s\sum_{i=0}^{n}C^{(s)}_{n-i,g-1} x^n + \left(\sum_{i=0}^s x^i\right) \sum_{n=s+1}^\infty C^{(s)}_{n-i,g} x^{n-i}\\
f_g^{(s)}(x) &= \left(\sum_{n=0}^s\sum_{i=0}^{n} -  \sum_{i=0}^{s} \sum_{n=0}^s\right)C^{(s)}_{n-i,g-1} x^n + \frac{1-x^{s+1}}{1-x} f_{g-1}^{(s)}(x)\,,
\end{aligned}
$$
where we used that $\sum_{i=0}^s x^i=(1-x^{s+1})/(1-x)$.
The summations on the right-hand side cancel out, because they differ only by terms for which $C_{n,s}^{(s)}$ are outside their support, and hence
$$
f_g^{(s)}(x) = \frac{1-x^{s+1}}{1-x} f_{g-1}^{(s)}(x) \implies \boxed{f_g^{(s)}(x) = \left( \frac{1-x^{s+1}}{1-x} \right)^g}
$$
on account of $f_0^{(s)}=0$. We can extract the $x^n$ coefficient using Newton's binomial formula and the Taylor expansion of the denominator, obtaining
$$
C^{(s)}_{n,g}= \sum_{k=0}^g (-1)^k \binom{g}{k}\binom{n-1+n-k(s-1)}{g-1}\,.
$$

If instead we are interested in the analogous combinatorics $D_{n,g}^{(s)}$ for *distinguishable* spheres, taking into account the fact that we can choose the first $i$ spheres in $\binom{n}{i}$ ways, we need to start from the recurrence relation
$$
D_{n,g}^{(s)} = \sum_{i=0}^{\mathrm{min}(n,s)} \binom{n}{i} D^{(s)}_{n-i, g-1}\,.
$$
Again, $D_{0,g}^{(s)}=1$ for $g\ge0$ and $D_{n,0}^{(s)}=0$ if $n\ge1$. In this case it is more convenient to employ the *exponential* generating functions
$$
F_g^{(s)}(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty D_{n,g}^{(s)} \frac{x^n}{n!}\,,
$$
which satisfy
$$
D_{n,g}^{(s)} = n! [z^n] F_g^{(s)}(x)\,.
$$
Also, $F_0^{(s)}=1$. Multiplying the recurrence relation by $x^n/n!$ and summing over $n$, as we did above, we get, after the analogous cancellations of low-$n$ terms,
$$
F_g^{(s)}(x)=\sum_{i=0}^s\frac{x^i}{i!}\sum_{n=0}^\infty D^{(s)}_{n-i, g-1} \frac{x^{n-i}}{(n-i)!}= \left(\sum_{i=0}^s\frac{x^i}{i!}\right) F_{g-1}^{(s)}(x)\,,
$$
hence, as already pointed out by @HammyTheGreek,
$$
\boxed{F_g^{(s)}(x) = \left(\sum_{i=0}^s\frac{x^i}{i!}\right)^g\,.}
$$
Using the multinomial coefficient, the answer can therefore be written as
$$
D^{(s)}_{n,g}=n! \sum_{\substack{\sum l_i=g\\\sum_i i l_i=n}} \binom{g}{l_1,l_2,\ldots,l_s}\frac{1}{\prod_i (i!)^{l_i}}\,.
$$

In the following particular cases, the generating functions give the ordinary combinations and $n$-permutations without repetitions or with an arbitrary number of repetitions:
$$
f_{g}^{(1)}=(1+x)^g\,,\qquad
f_{g}^{(\infty)}=(1-x)^{-g}\,,\qquad
F_{g}^{(1)}=(1+x)^g\,,\qquad
F_g^{(\infty)}=e^{gx}\,;
$$
$$
C_{n,g}^{(1)}=\binom{g}{n}\,,\qquad
C_{n,g}^{(\infty)}=\binom{g+n-1}{n}\,,\qquad
D_{n,g}^{(1)}=\frac{g!}{(g-n)!}\,,\qquad
D_{n,g}^{(\infty)}=g^n\,.
$$