# Combinations with maximum allowed Repetition

Tags: probability, combinatorics, extremal-combinatorics

There are how many ways to select $r$ things from $n$ categories with maximum $k$ repetitions are allowed from each category?

I think its only solvable if and only if $nk\ge r$ and I also believe that it's hard to find a formula for this problem but a generating function may be possible.

Comment: Here's an equivalent question with a generating function solution: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1106013/distinct-balls-and-distict-urns-with-constraint-maximum/1107480#1107480

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $c(r,n,k)$ be the number of ways to do this.  Consider conditioning on the number of items from the last category.  If you select $i$ of these, you still have to select $r-i$ from $n-1$ categories, still with at most $k$ repetitions allowed.  Thus we get the recursion
$$ \eqalign{c(r,n,k) &= \sum_{i=0}^{\min(r,k)} c(r-i,n-1,k)\cr
c(r,0,k) &= 0 \ \text{if}\ r > 0\cr
c(0,n,k) &= 1}$$

If $g(x, y, k) = \sum_{r,n \ge 0} c(r,n,k) x^r y^n $ is the generating function (for fixed $k$), this translates to 
$$ g(x,y,k) = 1 + \sum_{i=0}^k x^i y g(x,y,k)  = 1 + \dfrac{1-x^{k+1}}{1-x} y g(x,y,k)$$
and thus 
$$ g(x,y,k) = \dfrac{1-x}{1 - x - y + x^{k+1} y} $$