# Probability of m choose k from n objects

Tags: probability

Data is stored in $n$ memory blocks. A user reads the blocks in random order (uniform distribution). Find the probability that each block was read no more than $k$ times, provided that there were a total of $m$ readings.

Comment: What are your thoughts?

Comment: 1 - (n * p(m - k + 1))

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be equivalent to : place randomly $m$ balls into $n$ urns, find the probability that no urn has more than $k$ balls.

This does [not](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1106013/distinct-balls-and-distict-urns-with-constraint-maximum) [have](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2657146/what-is-the-probability-that-throwing-m-balls-at-random-in-n-urns-at-least-o) a simple (exact) solution.